# Create a java REST client to call a spring boot REST API

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have a springboot project that takes only POST JSON String which I'm converting to HashMap using gson. I tested using Postman as a POST and add the body as `props` with a json string like `{'fistname': 'John', 'lastname' : 'Doe'}`, translates to `props = {'fistname': 'John', 'lastname' : 'Doe'}`. its working as expected

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/rest", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    protected String parse(@RequestParam("props") String props) {
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
    params = gson.fromJson(props, Map.class);

    // Rest of the process
}
```

On the other hand, I have a JavaEE project, which needs to call this API

```
protected void callREST() {

      try {
            String json = someClass.getDate() //retrieved from database which is stored as json structure
            Map<String, String> props = gson.fromJson(json, Map.class);

            URL url = new URL("http://localhost:9090/myApp/rest");
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setDoOutput(true);
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");

            DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream( conn.getOutputStream());

            System.out.println(props.toString());
            wr.writeBytes(json.toString());
            wr.flush();
            wr.close();
            if(conn.getResponseCode() != HttpURLConnection.HTTP_CREATED) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Failed :: HTTP error code : " + conn.getResponseCode());
            }

            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
            String output;
            System.out.println("Output from Server ... \n");
            while((output = br.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(output);
            }

            conn.disconnect();

       } catch(Exception e) {
          //print stack trace
       }
 }
```

I get `Failed :: HTTP error code : 400`. I suspect the spring boot is not receiving the data in `props` variable since its a POST request.
What should i add in the client code to pass the props and the data to make this call successful ?

> Note: JavaEE is running on tomcat :8080, Springboot is running on
>   different tomcat :9090

Comment: Have a look at Spring"s `RestTemplate` class, it is very useful for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@RequestParam` means that server awaits param in request URL `http://localhost:9090/myApp/rest?param=.....` but in you client you are writing JSON in body of request.

Try to use `@RequestBody` annotation in your endpoint

```
protected String parse(@RequestBody String props) {...}
```

Comment: How can I make this async ?

Answer (score 1):

Your resources expects to get form parameters (i.e. key value pairs, using x-www-form-urlencoded encoding), where the value happens to be JSON (although what you posted is not valid JSON).

But your client Java code sets the content type to application/json, and sends the JSON as the body, instead of sending it as the value of the key "props" of a x-www-form-urlencoded body.

So that can't work.

If you can change the server, then do that. Accept JSON as the body directly:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/rest", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String parse(@RequestBody Map<String, String> map) {
     ...
}
```

If not, you'll need to send the correct key value pair, and make sure the value is properly url-encoded.